# Utilizing the same view for edit and view in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller action as follows

```
public ActionResult OpenForm()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

And my View is as follows [Index.cshtml]

```
@model BusinessProcess.Models.HelloworldTO
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Response_Borrower)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Response_Borrower)
}
```

Now the problem is I am using the same view for both "Edit" and "View". Now under certain circumstances I want the user to only "View" the data and convert the `@Html.EditorFor` to be `@Html.DisplayFor`. Is there any way to do it without creating another view?

Comment: `certain circumstances` - can these be expressed in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model:

```
public class HelloworldTO()
{
   public bool Edit {get; set;}
}
```

View:

```
@model BusinessProcess.Models.HelloworldTO
@if (Model.Edit)
{
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Response_Borrower)
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Response_Borrower)

   }
}
else
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Response_Borrower)
 }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult OpenForm()
{
    HelloworldTO model = new HelloworldTO ();
    model.Edit = /*certain circumstances*/;
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Model

```
  public class Model1
{
    public bool SameView { get; set; }

    public bool Response_Borrower { get; set; }


}
```

View

```
@model CodeProjectAnswers.Models.Model1
```

@if (Model.SameView)
{

```
// Do what you want
```

}
else
{ 
 // code for the display

}

and in the controller some like below

```
  public ActionResult Sample()
    {

        Model1 model = new Model1();

        if (model.SameView)
        {
            // Set it to false and what is ur condition 
        }
        else
        {
            model.SameView = true;
        }

        return View("Sample", model);


    }
```